# How do i get a Retrofit Response of some particular Objects and sort them?

Tags: android, kotlin, interface, retrofit, jsonobjectrequest

i am using Retrofit and i am getting the response without any problems, i am fetching the data and everything works well, but i only need to get the items with `projectType == "FOLDER"`, discarding the `projectType == "PROJECT"` ones.

How can i manage this? I also want to sort them based on creation date.

```
interface ApiInterface {


@GET("projects")
fun getData(@Header("secretKey") apiKey : String): Call<ProjectList>}
```

Sample output:

```
{
"projects": [
    {
        "id": "00001",
        "creation": 1611162020,
        "projectType": "FOLDER",
        "name": "3 - Aufträge",        
        "archived": false
    },
    {
        "id": "00002",
        "creation": 1611158408,          
        "projectType": "PROJECT",
        "name": "Unter",
        "archived": false
    },
    {
        "creation": 122234,
        "name": "4 - Aus",
        "id": "00003",           
        "projectType": "FOLDER",
        "archived": false
    }]}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a filter on result? `pList.projects.filter{ it.projectType == "FOLDER" }`

Comment: @Amin i will give it a try!! and i will let you know :)

Comment: it did not work..it is still showing me the  projectType == "PROJECT" any idea why?

Comment: Now it works!! :) @Amin thank you very much .. but one last question - can i sort them by creationDate?  in the same way... from the response/result ? thank youuu :)

Comment: I wrote an answer because it's gonna be a little huge for comments section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  easily filter your items using filter function as shown below

```
pList.projects.filter{ it.projectType == "FOLDER" }
```

Also if you want to sort your items based on a property, you can use `sortedBy` and `sortedByDescending` like below

```
val ans = pList.projects
    .filter{ it.projectType == "FOLDER" }
    .sortedBy { it.position.creation }
```

And for reversed order

```
val ans = pList.projects
    .filter{ it.projectType == "FOLDER" }
    .sortedByDescending { it.position.creation }
```